# does hadoop namenode dirs synchronize after a failure?

Tags: hadoop, backup, redundancy

What happens in this scenario:
Namenode is writing to two directories on two different drives, one is local and the other (remote) is mounted . Now, the namenode fails and we launch namenode process on the remote machine (it has a copy of the original namenode data, so it's safe) and change namenode's ip on all datanodes. After a while, we manage to bring the original namenode to life with exact previous configuration. We stop the namenode process on the remote machine. Now, will the local fs.name.dir be synchronized with the mounted one (I mean the diff which was accumulated on the mounted dir, while the original namenode was down) or there will be a problem with namenode data consistency?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, will the local fs.name.dir be synchronized with the mounted one (I mean the diff which was accumulated on the mounted dir, while the original namenode was down) or there will be a problem with namenode data consistency?

The local NN data will be out-of-date for the time it was down. All the changes done to the NN namespace on the remote will not be there on the local NN.

Note than NN only stores the namespace for the filesystem and also the namespace to block-id mapping. Where the blocks are stored is not stored in NN. When a DN starts, it sends the block report to the NN.

Check [this](http://hadoop-tips.blogspot.com/2011/11/hdfs-name-node-high-availability.html) and [this](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hadoop-namenode-high-availability.html) on the HDFS NN HA.

> change namenode's ip on all datanodes.
>   After a while, we manage to bring the original namenode to life with exact previous configuration. We stop the namenode process on the remote machine.

There will be downtime for the above mentioned scenarios.